# Cannot get Ubuntu to recognize Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have installed Windows 7 on my laptop and then wanted to go and install Ubuntu 12.04 afterwards. When I installed Windows 7 I created a couple of spare partitions. I then used the Ubuntu USB boot method (and later on I downloaded the normal 12.04 desktop 64 bit Ubuntu). Whenever I insert the Ubuntu CD in and then select to install Ubuntu it never recognised the 64 bit Windows 7 installation.

I have managed to do this in the past (and I swear I had Windows 7 first and then Ubuntu second).

Could someone please advise/help? I have now used three different Windows 7 installation disks and 2 Ubuntu (USB stick 12.04 twice).

Comment: You sure that you shutdown (no suspend, sleep or hibernate) the Windows? Also, you sure that the NTFS disk isn't dirty? Open Gparted and look for a warning symbol.

Answer (score 0):

installing windows first and Ubuntu second is the correct order, if you install windows later it will remove the grub menu. I do not know why it does not recognize your windows installation, but you could try to [reinstall grub with boot-repair on a live cd or usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) after you install Ubuntu.